# Jquery .resize won't be triggered

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, resize

Following the W3Schools, i tried the following to trigger a resize event :

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(".formEvent").length){ // If element exist
            addEventForm($("span.active")); // resize process
        }
    });
    console.log($(window).data("events"));
});
```

Why he will not trigger my event ?

Edit : The addEventForm work, because he is triggered on time to create my element when there is a click.

### EDIT2 :

Here is the addEventform function :

```
function addEventForm(jour){
    if(!$(".formEvent").length){
        jour.closest("tr").after("<form class='formEvent'><div class='curseur'></div></form>");
    }
    
    var percent = jour.offset().left-jour.closest("tr").offset().left+parseInt(jour.css("margin-left").replace("px", ""))+ parseInt(jour.css("padding-left").replace("px", ""))+parseInt(jour.css("border-left-width").replace("px", ""));
    $(".formEvent .curseur").css({"top" : "-15px" , "left": percent+"px"});
    $(".formEvent").show()
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. How have you determined the event isn't being triggered? Are you sure it's not an error in your code? Have you checked the console?

Comment: I've checked the console, no error, but for the console.log of the $(window), i got undefined

Comment: Have you defined any `data` properties on the window? Your code doesn't show any

Comment: No but as i read, when we had a event listener , it Will be added like so

Comment: Have u imported jQuery?

Comment: The method you're using to do that is outdated - typical W3Schools idiocy. You need to use the internal jQuery data object to retrieve attached event details: `console.log($._data(window, "events"));`: https://jsfiddle.net/8cudp2n1/ Also note that this won't trigger the event, only check it is hooked to the provided element.

Comment: jquery imported.
Yes, it's what i want to do, because as i saw, the event is not fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my correct. It's really obscur...

```
window.onresize = function(){
    if($(".formEvent").length){
        addEventForm($("span.active"));
    }
};
```

Using the Javascript API, everithing is working fine. So let's keep this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put a console log inside your resize function and its fired as expected.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log('check');
        if($(".formEvent").length){ // If element exist
            addEventForm($("span.active")); // resize process
        }
    });
    console.log($(window).data("events"));
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNLoRb?editors=1112

Something inside your if statement must be breaking.

Comment: Hum, yes as i saw. Will edit the post to show you my addEventForm function